# SPFx: Failed to load path dependency from component

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to create a SPFx webpart and use a jQuery plugin. Below are the steps I followed.

1. Created a SPFx solution using yo
2. Installed jQuery through NPM
3. Installed jQuery.payment (plugin) through NPM
4. Updated them as external dependencies

   ```
     "externals": {
     "jquery":{
         "path":"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
         "globalName":"jquery"
     },
     "jquery.payment":{
       "path":"node_modules/jquery.payment/lib/jquery.payment.min.js",
       "globalName":"jquery",
       "globalDependencies":["jquery"]
     }
   ```
5. Used the following import statement in my webpart file

   ```
   import * as $ from 'jquery';    import 'jquery.payment';
   ```
6. Tired to call the plugin method

   ```
   $("input.cardBox").payment('formatCardNumber');
   ```
7. Run gulp serve
8. Open in local workbench (Works as expected)
9. Open in SharePoint workbench (https:///_layouts/15/workbench.aspx). Throws the following error

> Error: ***Failed to load path dependency
>   "0d6d6e17-e715-4f63-8e52-f3e5b69c8089" from component "DemoWebPart"
>   (Error loading
>   https://component-id.invalid/0d6d6e17-e715-4f63-8e52-f3e5b69c8089_0.0.1/jquery.payment
>     Evaluating
>   https://localhost:4321/node_modules/jquery.payment/lib/jquery.payment.min.js
>     jquery is not defined). Original error: {3}

I have followed this thread from github
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/336, where the issues was on local workbench.
However, this is not working for me on SharePoint workbench and working fine on my local workbench.

Following are the npm module versions I am using[image: npm module versions]

Answer (score 1):

I saw that the global variable where jQuery is stored is **'jQuery'** and not **'jquery'** (notice the capitalization).
When trying to access 'jquery' in the browser console I get the same error.

Just change the *globalName* to *"jQuery"* and it should work properly.